# CSS variables in Safari

Tags: css

Im creating an app that uses css and html.

One page uses a css media query along with display:grid

All of the sizes seem fine on all browsers except Safari. The sizes don't seem to compute properly and the grid rows merge into themselves.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Ive got a variable called --vh which is 1% of the window.innerHeight so that I can negate the browsers toolbars. This works fine just not in a media query in safari.

Any help would be appreciated.

If you want to try it out live visit https://trivia.house
Host a game on a laptop or a device and then join the game on the safari enabled device. The issue is with the first question screen where the app will stop and hold. if yo udo the same on edge or chrome it renders fine.

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

This is how it renders - excuse the poor quality of the safari one!

[image]

This is the rendered code: (I have tried SVH and DVH and same happens)

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="icon" href="https://trivia.house/favicon.ico">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
        <meta name="description" content="Free Multiplayer Online Trivia Quiz Games">
        <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
        <title>Carousel Quiz | Free Multiplayer Online Games | Trivia House</title>
        <script defer="defer" src="/static/js/main.d9851aae.js"></script>
        <link href="/static/css/main.69f4b861.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
    
        <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>

        <div id="root">
            <div class="App">
                <div class="AppResolution">
                    <p id="ResolutionIssueMessage">THIS APPLICATION CAN ONLY BE RUN ON A PORTRAIT-ORIENTATED DEVICE, PLEASE EXPAND THE BROWSER WINDOW TO A SUPPORTED SIZE.</p>
                </div>
                
                <div class="AppContent">
                    
                    <div id="questionWrapper">
                        <div id="questionContainer">
                            <div className="questionBox title">
                                <div className="vText">
                                    <img id="titleQuestion" src='' />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div id="roundInfo" className="questionBox roundInfo"><div className='vText'>Question 1</div></div>
                            <div id="gameCode" className="questionBox gameCode"></div>       
                            <div id="question" className="questionBox question"><div className='vText'>question</div></div>
                            <div id="scores" className="questionBox scores">Scores</div>
                            <div id="answer1" className="questionBox answer1"><div className='vText'>answer1</div></div>
                            <div id="answer2" className="questionBox answer2"><div className='vText'>answer2</div></div>
                            <div id="answer3" className="questionBox answer3"><div className='vText'>answer3</div></div>
                            <div id="answer4" className="questionBox answer4"><div className='vText'>answer4</div></div>
                            <div id="timer" className="questionBox timer"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>      
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

This is the main CSS for this problem but there may be some missing as its a react app with LOTS of CSS all bundled together. If you need the whole let then let me know... as above though you can visit the site and see for yourself:

```
#questionWrapper{
  
  width: 100%;
  height: calc((var(--containerheight)) * 100px); 
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: black 1px solid;

}

#questionContainer{
  
  display:grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: calc(35% - 5px) calc(35% - 5px) calc(30%);
  grid-template-rows: 0.8fr 0.8fr 1.8fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  height: calc((var(--containerheight)) * 100px);
}

.questionBox {
  
  background-color: rgba(224, 38, 63, 0.6);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: calc(1vh + 1vw);
  font-weight: 800;
  text-align: center;
}

#titleQuestion{
  width: 100%;
  animation: bounce-in-right 2s ease;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.title {
  display: table;
  overflow: clip;
  background-color: rgba(224, 38, 63, 0);
  text-align: center;
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 1/3;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.roundInfo {

  display: table;
  grid-column: 3/4;
  grid-row: 1/2;
  font-size: calc(1.25vh + 1.25vw);
}

.gameCode {
  text-align: center;
  grid-column: 3/4;
  grid-row: 2/3;
  background-color: rgba(224, 38, 63, 0);
  
}
.question {
  display: table;
  background-color: rgba(224, 38, 63, 0);
  font-size: calc(1.4vh + 1.4vw);
  color: rgba(224, 38, 63, 1);
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 3/4 ;
}
.scores {
  grid-column: 3/4;
  grid-row: 3/7;
}
.answer1 {
  display: table;
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 4/5;
}
.answer2 {
  display: table;
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 4/5;
}
.answer3 {
  display: table;
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 5/6;
}
.answer4 {
  display: table;
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 5/6;
}
.timer {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 6/7;
}



.vText{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;

}


/***************************************************************/
@media (max-width: 1000px){



  #questionContainer{
  
    display:grid;
    grid-gap: calc((var(--containerheight))*0.5px);
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
    grid-template-rows: 0px calc((var(--containerheight))*10px) calc((var(--containerheight))*26px) repeat(5,calc((var(--containerheight))*12px));
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .questionBox {
    background-color: rgba(224, 38, 63, 0.6);
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 15px;
    font-size: calc(1.2vh + 1.2vw);
    font-weight: 800;
    text-align: center;   
  }

  .roundInfo {
    display: table;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    grid-row: 2/3;
  }

  .question {
    display: table;
    background-color: rgba(224, 38, 63, 0);
    font-size: calc(1.2vh + 1.2vw);
    color: rgba(224, 38, 63, 1);;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    grid-row: 3/4;
  }

  .answer1 {
    display: table;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    grid-row: 4/5;
     
  }
  .answer2 {
    display: table;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    grid-row: 5/6;
  }
  .answer3 {
    display: table;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    grid-row: 6/7;
  }
  .answer4 {
    display: table;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    grid-row: 7/8;
  }
  .timer {
    display: table;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    grid-row: 8/9;
  }

 

#GameCodeWidget{
  display: none;
}

#gameCode{
  display: none;
}
 
.title{
  display: none;
}

.scores{
  display: none;
}

}
```

Comment: In theory Safari should be able to support all of these features.  Please provide a code sample and maybe someone will spot an issue.  Also which version of Safari are you running?

Comment: How do you expect us to help without sharing some actual code?

Comment: Sorry guys code added!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a variable, you just need to use small viewport units — `svh`. The value `1svh` will be equal to your variable `var(--vh)`.

The CSS spec now includes three additional variants of `vh`: `svh`, `lvh` and `dvh`. [Read about them here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-4/#viewport-variants). These variants account for various configurations of toolbars in mobile browsers. You can use these variants in [all major browsers](https://caniuse.com/viewport-unit-variants).

Note that iOS Safari currently has a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76303977/svh-units-not-working-properly-in-mobile-safari) where `svh` and `dvh` yield the same values in all circumstances. However, this may not affect what you want to do.

Comment: This may save my life! thanks so much. it just goes to show how important knowledge is and picking these things up in forums. ill give it a try. Apple seriously need to up their game.

Comment: Update:  I have switched the above CSS variables to simple svh units. everything worked fine again EXCEPT in Safari... is this expected because of the bug? It appears that Safari sees svh as vh...?

Comment: If you edit your question to include a snippet which demonstrates the problem I will comment further. Base your snippet on your compiled HTML/CSS (view source in the browser) rather than your React source.

Comment: I have put code snippet in my question Brett. See above. If the SVH unit is actually the DVH figure then that may explain why things are looking odd.